# How to pass Java Date in Spring Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring

If I have a Java Date and, using JDBCTEmplate i want to use it in a prepared statement, is this the right syntax?

```
Date x = new Date();

...

String SQL = "select a.1, a.2 from b JOIN a ON b.id = a.b_id where b.name = ? and a.type = ? and a.date = ?";

A istance = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{variable_1, variable_2, x}, new aAndbMapper());
```

Or I should write:

```
String SQL = "select a.1, a.2 from b JOIN a ON b.id = a.b_id where b.name = ? and a.type = ? and DATE(a.date) = ?";
```

Comment: First one is the better solution for me

Comment: use object of `java.sql.Date` class as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is a good option, though I would do it without custom mapper:

```
String SQL = "select a.1, a.2 from b JOIN a ON b.id = a.b_id where b.name = ? and a.type = ? and a.date = ?";

A istance = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{variable_1, variable_2, x}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(A.class));
```

More on beanPropertymapper: [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.0/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html)